# Android Studio (KOTLIN) is not recognizing a Public Method? seekTo (long msec, int mode) [Added in API level 26]

Tags: kotlin, mediacontroller

Kotlin just let me select "seekTo (int msec)" but I need to use "seekTo (long msec, int mode)"

Im using API 27 and I have all this imported:

```
import androidx.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlin.*
import kotlin.text.*
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.text.Editable
import androidx.core.*
import android.media.*
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener
import android.media.MediaPlayer.*
import android.support.*



VIDEO!!.seekTo(10000)
seekTo (int msec) //Just let me select this
seekTo (long msec, int mode) //this so not apear
```

And still not working, don't let me select it. any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: `10000` is an Int constant.  If you want a Long one, use `10000L`.  Also, what type is `VIDEO`?

Comment: VIDEO its a videoView and the problem is the android studio, I mean, its something I miss to add, because if I start to write AAA.seekT....  then Android Studio show me the "available options", and just show me "seekTo (int msec)" never show  "seekTo (long msec, int mode) "